# How can I use an existing field as a modifier to the $match inside my Mongo aggregation query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My data structure is akin to:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5a7f534b337e8d2b97ff2ff"),
  cutoff: 3,
  schedules: [
    {
      starts: ISODate('2020-04-22T00:00:00.000Z'),
      ends: ISODate('2020-04-22T00:00:00.000Z'),
      repeats: 'never'
    },
    {
      starts: ISODate('2020-04-30T00:00:00.000Z'),
      ends: ISODate('2020-06-30T00:00:00.000Z'),
      repeats: 'monthly'
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to build a query which searches by an overlapping date range, i.e:

```js
  const from = new Date(2020, 04, 25)
  const to = new Date(2020, 05, 5)

  await datastore
    .collection('things')
    .aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          'schedules.starts': { $lte: to },
          'schedules.ends': { $gte: from }
        }
      }
    ])
```

The issue being that I need to factor in the cutoff to the search, so I discovered `$expr` and tried to apply it to my query:

```js
$match: {
  'schedules.starts': { $lte: to.toDate() },
  'schedules.ends': { $expr: { $gte: { $add: [ from.toDate(), { $multiply: [ '$cutoff', 24, 60, 60000 ] } } } }
}
```

I've tried no end of experimentation with `$expr` to get it to work within the query, but I either get an error about it being incorrectly used, or I don't get any results back. I'm not sure how to proceed.

I've considered using `$project` or `$addFields` before the match to simplify, but I understand from the manual that this will cause my multi-key indexes to stop working.

Comment: I think you have to use the aggregation version of the [$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/index.html), since you are using the gte operator with the `$expr`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$match` condition is not really clear for me. In general you can use existing fields:

```
var from = new Date(2020, 04, 25)
var to = new Date(2020, 05, 5)

db.collection.aggregate([
   { $addFields: { from: from } },
   { $addFields: { to: to } },
   { $addFields: { ends: { $toDate: { $add: [from.getTime(), { $multiply: ['$cutoff', 24, 60, 60, 1000] }] } } } }
])
```

returns

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e5530e922139e9b31aa786c"), 
    "cutoff" : 3.0, 
    "schedules" : [
        {
            "starts" : ISODate("2020-04-22T02:00:00.000+0200"), 
            "ends" : ISODate("2020-04-22T02:00:00.000+0200"), 
            "repeats" : "never"
        }, 
        {
            "starts" : ISODate("2020-04-30T02:00:00.000+0200"), 
            "ends" : ISODate("2020-06-30T02:00:00.000+0200"), 
            "repeats" : "monthly"
        }
    ], 
    "from" : ISODate("2020-05-25T00:00:00.000+0200"), 
    "to" : ISODate("2020-06-05T00:00:00.000+0200"), 
    "ends" : ISODate("2020-05-28T00:00:00.000+0200")
}
```

In order you use it in `$match` it would be

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         $expr: {
            $gte: [
               "$schedules.ends",
               { $toDate: { $add: [from.getTime(), { $multiply: ['$cutoff', 24, 60, 60, 1000] }] } }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Hi Wernfried - thanks for this, however I believe that $addFields is a projection operator, so this will mean that my query no longer uses indexing, is this correct?

Comment: Of course, the first query does not use any index as it returns all documents anyway.